# Error Missing required parameters for [Route] after upgrading Laravel 5.8 to 6.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

After upgrading **Laravel 5.8** to **6.0** I get the below error:

> local.ERROR: Missing required parameters for [Route:
> playlist-song.show] [URI: public/admin/playlist-song/{playlist_song}].
> {"userId":1,"exception":"[object]
> (Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException(code:
> 0):Missing required parameters for [Route: playlist-song.show] [URI:
> public/admin/playlist-song/{playlist_song}].at
> /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Exceptions/UrlGenerationException.php:17)

Chrome Inspect Result:

[image: chrome inspect error for laravel]

I have tried to find error and update route using `_` or `-` but still can't solve this error:

any idea to solve this issue?

Thank You in Advance...

===Update

1. **I suspect error here:**

```
$datatables = app('datatables')->of($model)
 ->addColumn('action', function ($model) {
                return "<a href='". route('playlist-song.show', ['id' => $model->id]) ."' class='btn btn-success btn-sm'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></a>" . 
                        " <a href='". route('playlist-song.edit', ['id' => $model->id]) . "' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'><i class='fas fa-pencil-alt'></i></a>" .
                        " <a href='#' onClick='modalDelete(".$model->id.")' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger'><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></a>";                        
});
```

2. Update the URL like below still can not solve the problem:

> href='". {{ route('playlist-song.show', ['playlist-song' => $model])
> }}."'
>
> href="{{ route('playlist-song.show',
> ['playlist-song' => $model]) }}"

Comment: As far as I remember, it has to be: `{{ route('playlist-song.edit', ['playlist_song' => $model]) }}` for it to work correctly

Comment: @CornelRaiu Hi thanks for the comment, i've tried it but still error, i think error at `index.blade.php` at jQuery `url` specifically at `ajax` --> `url: '{!! route('playlist-song.list-index') !!}',` but i dont know why

Comment: The error literally tells you which route it is: "_for [Route: playlist-song.show]_" So no, it is _not_ your jQuery/ajax url

Comment: @brombeer but if I remove all link contain `Route` in `show.blade.php` then error still exists and if I remove URL in `Ajax` param in `index.blade.php` then Error become different/404

Comment: Not sure why you'd remove all routes in `show.blade.php`. The error doesn't state it's _in_ `show.blade.php`, but you have a link somewhere that points to that route - either in a `.blade` view or a Controller redirect or something. Search your project for `playlist-song.show` and see where the parameter is missing

Comment: @brombeer i have found what caused the error, now data can show after close some lines in controller, but any idea to fix it?

Comment: As @CornelRaiu suggested, use `['playlist_song' => $model]` as parameter (since your route is a resource route) instead of `['id' => $model->id]`

Comment: I have tried add `href='". {{ route('playlist-song.show', ['playlist-song' => $model]) }}."'` or like this `href="{{ route('playlist-song.show', ['playlist-song' => $model]) }}"` but still cant solve the error

Comment: what are your route definitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error tells you that your `playlist_song` parameter is missing. You will need to specify its value. A try would be

```
$datatables = app('datatables')->of($model)
 ->addColumn('action', function ($model) {
                return "<a href='". route('playlist-song.show', ['playlist_song' => $model->id]) ."' class='btn btn-success btn-sm'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></a>" . 
                        " <a href='". route('playlist-song.edit', ['playlist_song' => $model->id]) . "' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'><i class='fas fa-pencil-alt'></i></a>" .
                        " <a href='#' onClick='modalDelete(".$model->id.")' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger'><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></a>";                        
});
```

This specifies the parameter. If you still have problems, then let me know what your new error message/problem is.

Comment: perfect answer!

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by using view also as the following:

```
$datatables = app('datatables')->of($model)
 ->addColumn('action', function($model) {
                return view('partial.action', compact('model'));
            });
```

create your view where you want, and you can put inside it normal html code without concatenation and any other issue

the blade file :

```
 <a href="{{ route('playlist-song.show', ['id' => $model->id]) }}" class='btn btn-success btn-sm'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></a>
 <a href="{{ route('playlist-song.edit', ['id' => $model->id]) }}" class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'><i class='fas fa-pencil-alt'></i></a>
 <a href='#' onClick="modalDelete('{{$model->id}}')" class='btn btn-sm btn-danger'><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></a>
```